# embedded C: Skips a function call

Tags: c, function, embedded

I am programming a RX63N development board and trying to do the following by modifying an existing tutorial:
initially pattern1 of onboard LEDs should glow till a switch is pressed and if any switch is pressed the pattern2 should start and then on pressing any switch all the LEDs should turn off.I have initialized all the constants and the function prototypes at the top but haven't included here for brevity sake.
BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS should enable an infinite loop till any switch is pressed and if after 1st appearance of it, the pattern2 should start and then after the second appearance of it, all leds should turn off. But here, the code directly goes from pattern 1 to stopped skipping pattern 2.Can someone please help?
Here's the code:

```
void main(void){
cmt_init(); /* Initialize the CMT unit for application timing tasks. */ 

R_SWITCHES_Init(); /* Prepare the board switches for use. */

/* Set up the callback function on cmt channel 0 */   
cmt_callback_set(CHANNEL_0, &BLINK_RED_LEDS);

/* Start 400mS count on cmt channel 0. */
cmt_start(CHANNEL_0, TIMER_COUNT_400MS);

BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS();
state = 0;

/* Stop counting on cmt channel 0. */
cmt_stop(CHANNEL_0);

/* Set up the callback function on cmt channel 0 */   
cmt_callback_set(CHANNEL_0, &PATTERN);

/* Start 200mS count on cmt channel 0. */
cmt_start(CHANNEL_0, TIMER_COUNT_200MS);
switch_press == 0;
BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS();

gstate = 0;
/* Stop counting on cmt channel 0. */
cmt_stop(CHANNEL_0);


while (1)
{
    /* All done. Loop here forever. LEDs will continue to flash as 
       at a variable rate as the timer ISR executes. */
}
} /* End of function main(). */

/*Reset all LEDs */
void RESET_ALL_LEDS(void){
PORTD.PODR.BYTE = 0xFF;       /* Turn off all LEDs on port D.*/
PORTE.PODR.BYTE |= 0x0F;      /* Turn off all LEDs on port E.*/
state = 0;                   /*state of RED LEDs*/
gstate = 0;                  /*state of greeen LEDs*/
}

/*All RED LEDS ON */
void ALL_RED_LEDS_ON(void){
PORTD.PODR.BYTE = ~0xC7;  /*Turns on all the RED LEDS on port D*/
PORTE.PODR.BYTE = ~0x01;    /*Turns on the RED LED on port E */
state = 1;                  /*update state*/
}

/*BLOCK UNTIL SWITCH PRESS:
g_swX_press is  predefined bool to detect a switch press and initiated false*/
void BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS(void){
while(switch_press == 0){
    if(g_sw1_press == true){
        switch_press = 1 ;
        }
    else if(g_sw2_press == true){
        switch_press = 1 ;
    }
    else if(g_sw3_press == true){
        switch_press = 1 ;
    }   
}
g_sw1_press == false;
g_sw2_press == false;
g_sw3_press == false;
}

/*BLINK RED LEDS */
void BLINK_RED_LEDS(void){
if (state == 1){
    ALL_RED_LEDS_ON();
    state = 0;
}
else if(state == 0){
    RESET_ALL_LEDS();
    state = 1;  
}   
}

void ALL_GREEN_LEDS_ON(void){
PORTD.PODR.BYTE = ~0x38;     /*Turns on all the Green LEDS on port D*/
PORTE.PODR.BYTE = ~0xFE;    /*Turns on all the Green LEDS on port E*/
gstate = 1;
}

/*CUSTOM PATTERN */
void PATTERN (void){
if (gstate == 1){
    ALL_GREEN_LEDS_ON();
    gstate = 0;
}
else if(gstate == 0){
    RESET_ALL_LEDS();
    gstate = 1; 
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the definitions of your global variables: `gstate`, `g_sw1_press`, etc.

Comment: Get a half-decent compiler which warns for "assignment in expression" and "code has no effect". I'm really curious what piece of crap compiler that let this code slide without giving any warnings.

Comment: There is no language "Embedded C". Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them! And if your LEDs "glow", you really should reduce their current!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jayant already answered, by writing `switch_press == 0` you are not assigning zero to `switch_press`, but instead evaluating a boolean expression (like when you write an `if` function). You did this at several places.

To add to his answer, you might also want to simplify your blocking function to something like:

```
// it looks like you don't need "switch_press" at all
void BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS(void) {

    // loop until one of the switches is pressed
    while (!g_sw1_press && !g_sw2_press && !g_sw3_press)
    { 
       // do nothing (or you can put the cpu to sleep for a while)
    }

    // do you even need to reset these?
    g_sw1_press = false;
    g_sw2_press = false;
    g_sw3_press = false;
}
```

Comment: Multiple assignments on the same row is by no means better style than having them on separate rows. In fact, having them on the same row is dangerous and bad practice! Because in case any of the operands contains side effects, you'll invoke undefined behavior, which will result in very subtle but potentially devastating bugs.

Comment: @Lundin: the point was to simplify the `while` loop and fix the incorrect "assignment" made by OP (`g_sw1_press == false`), I admit I wrote whatever was outside the loop in a single row for no special reason and then decided to add the comment. But anyway, I would like to hear how this line could possibly ever fail; which operands could have side effects when assigning an integer literal to multiple variables?

Comment: To make an overly obvious example, suppose you have `a[f()] = b[f()] = c[f()] = false;`, where `f()` is a function calculating an array index based on an internal counter. You can't tell which of the 3 function calls that will be executed first, so the outcome of the code can't be known.

Comment: A more realistic example may be the very code in the OPs question, where the 3 variables would seem to be `volatile`, possibly directly corresponding to an I/O port. In that case `g_sw3_press` will first get the value `false` written to it, and after that it may potentially update to something else. And then "something else" will be written to the other two variables, instead of the value `false`.

Comment: @Lundin: good call, you're completely right, I will fix my post.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment before the function call `BLOCK_UNTIL_SWITCH_PRESS();` is wrong

```
switch_press == 0;
```

Should be

```
switch_press = 0;
```

Comment: +1 OP also made the same mistake several times throughout the code (like `g_sw1_press == false` and others).